# Wie beugt man den Nikolaus?

Tags: grammar, noun, inflection

Am heutigen 6. Dezember ist [Nikolaus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolaus_von_Myra). Ein Fest für die Kinder. Die fragen aber ihre klugen Eltern nach deutscher Grammatik:

> "Sind das nun Nikol**a**use oder Nikol**ä**use, die wir heute bekommen haben?"
>   "Müssen wir nach Aufessen des Nikolaus, oder des Nikolaus**es**, wirklich zur Schule?"

Was ist hier jeweils die "bessere", also gebräuchlichere Variante? Nach den Wörterbüchern ist offenbar alles erlaubt.

---

Nachdem es noch niemand erwähnt hat, hier noch ein Zusatz:
Mein Eindruck ist, dass man den Nikolaus aus Schokolade häufiger anders dekliniert als den männlichen Vornamen. Das ist aber wirklich nur ein Eindruck, für den ich keine Referenz gefunden habe. Es wäre interessant, wenn jemand etwas mehr darüber sagen könnte.

Comment: Lass doch den armen Mann in Ruhe. Dem tut der Rücken schon so weh genug, warum musst ihn noch beugen? ;D

Comment: +1 für den Titel! :D

Comment: Da die gebräuchliche Variante oft gerade nicht die bessere ist, ist die suggestive Fragestellung mit "also" zu kritisieren. Und zu 'gebräuchlich': Das kann nach Region variieren, nach Bildung, nach Alter und so fort. Wo sollte man die Gebräuchlichkeit ablesen?

Comment: Gleich wie "Stanislaus". *grins* ;)

Comment: Wenn er unartig war, übers Knie! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Nikolaus* ist vor allen Dingen erstmal ein Name. Und dann wird der Genitiv gebildet, wie man ihn auch mit anderen Namen, wie Hans, bilden würde.

> … nach dem Aufessen des Nikolaus …
>
> Nikolaus' Namenstag ist am sechsten Dezember.

In der Umgangssprache ist *Nikolauses* jedoch üblicher und Wiktionary listet dies auch als reguläre Form. Ich halte beide Varianten für richtig, wobei mit der Endung *-es* das Wort in meinen Ohren besser klingt.

Oder man befleißigt sich des Dativs, wie in

> Das ist das Haus vom Nikolaus.

Für den Plural listet Wiktionary erneut beide Varianten.

> Hinsichtlich der Pluralformen von Nikolaus finden sich in unterschiedlichen Quellen verschiedene Angaben zum Gebrauch: Einmal wird Nikoläuse als die überwiegend benutzte Form bezeichnet, während Nikolause selten sei. Andernorts wird Nikoläuse als umgangssprachliche und scherzhafte Pluralform klassifiziert im Gegensatz zu Nikolause, was die übliche Form sei. Daneben wird Nikoläuse auch als landschaftliche und oft scherzhaft gebrauchte Form bezeichnet.

Hier empfinde ich den Umlaut als die schönere Variante, genau so wie es auch *Mäuse* und *Läuse* sind, wenn's um das Nagetier bzw. das Insekt geht.

Answer (score 4):

Singular Nominativ:

> Der Mann mit dem verbrannten Ohr ist der Nikolaus.

Sinular Genitiv:

> Das ist des Nikolaus' kaputter Rennwagen.

Singular Dativ:

> Diese Airline hat einmal dem Nikolaus gehört.

Singular Akkusativ:

> Gestern hat man den Nikolaus wieder im Fernsehen gesehen.

Plural Nominativ:

> Der Mann mit nur einem Ohr und der Mann mit der Cola-Flasche sind zwei Nikolause.
>   Der Mann mit nur einem Ohr und der Mann mit der Cola-Flasche sind zwei Nikoläuse.

Plural Genitiv:

> Dieser Rennwagen und dieser Schlitten sind der beiden Nikolause Fahrzeuge.
>   Dieser Rennwagen und dieser Schlitten sind der beiden Nikoläuse Fahrzeuge.

Plural Dativ:

> Die rote Kappe und die rote Mütze gehören den beiden Nikolausen.
>   Die rote Kappe und die rote Mütze gehören den beiden Nikoläusen.

Plural Akkusativ:

> Niemand hat jemals die beiden Nikolause zur selben Zeit gesehen.
>   Niemand hat jemals die beiden Nikoläuse zur selben Zeit gesehen.

Comment: **zum Singular-Genitiv meine ich:** in diesem Beispiel *ohne* Apostroph, da es als Auslassungszeichen für ein Genitiv-s stünde (um ein Doppel-s zu vermeiden), das aber in einer Konstruktion mit **des** von vornherein gar nicht vorkommt: **des Nikolaus kaputter Rennwagen**, **das Haus des Nikolaus** wie auch **der Anne rotes Käppchen**. Der Apostroph gehört dagegen hinein in: **Ich habe Nikolaus’ kaputten Rennwagen repariert.**

Comment: Und ich dachte immer, der heißt Nicki (**mit** c natürlich!). ;-)

Comment: @TehMacDawg: Wieso kommt das Genitiv-s in einer Konstruktion mit **des** nicht vor?

Comment: @Mac: Das bezieht sich speziell auf die Flexion von Personennamen im heutigen Deutsch: Bei der Genitivbildung mit vorstehendem Artikel – *des* (m), *der* (f) *des* (n) oder *der* (Plural) – wird hier kein Genitiv-s benutzt. In früheren Jahrhunderten war das noch anders, was bei vielen zur Unsicherheit darüber beitragen mag. In der Linguistik wird so eine Entwicklung auch *Deflexion* genannt, s. [Nübling 2012: Auf dem Weg zu Nicht-Flektierbaren: Die Deflexion der deutschen Eigennamen(…)](http://www.germanistik.uni-mainz.de/pdfs/hist/Nuebling/Nubling%202012%20Eigennamendeflexion.pdf)

Comment: @Mac: Hier noch eine Darstellung der Genitivbildung bei Personennamen: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/FKlassen/Name-Person3.html

Comment: @TehMacDawg: Wunderbar, vielen Dank! :)

Answer (score 2):

Für den Plural scheint beides zulässig zu sein.
http://www.wortbedeutung.info/Nikolaus/

für den Genitiv sollten wohl `Nikolaus oder Nikolaus'` verwendet werden
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nikolaus_maennlicher_Vorname

Comment: Meiner Einschätzung nach wird die Pluralform "Nikoläuse" teilweise auch nicht scherzhaft verwendet, einfach weil es viele ähnliche Pluralbildungen gibt.